# Field of rational functions over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K=\mathbb{Z}_p(x,y)$ be the field of rational functions of variables $x,y$ with coefficients in the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$, where $p$ is prime.

Let $g(t)=t^p-x, h(t)=t^p-y \in K[t]$ and $E$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $f(t)=g(t) \cdot h(t) \in K[t]$.

Show that:

1. $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are irreducible polynomials of $K[t]$.
2. $[E:K]=p^2$
3. The extension $K \leq E$ is not separable.
4. $a^p \in K$ for each $a \in E$

Could you give me some hints how to show the above??

Is the splitting field $E=K(x^{\frac{1}{p}}, y^{\frac{1}{p}})$ ??

Answer (score 1):

**Hints.**

1. Use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009590/show-that-a-polynomial-is-irreducible-over-a-field-of-positive-characteristic) for $n=1$.
2. Use this tower of fields: $K\subset K(\sqrt[p]{x})\subset E$.
3. $\sqrt[p]{x}$ is not separable over $K$.
4. Use the freshmen's dream.

Yes, $E$ is the splitting field of $f$.

Comment: 1. We have the field $K=\mathbb{Z}_p(x,y)$. Does it stand that $\operatorname{char}K=p$??  ($p$ is a prime and $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_p(x,y)$). The polynomial $t^p-x \in K[t]$ is irreducible iff $x$ has no $p$th roots in $K$ and the polynomial $t^p-y \in K[t]$ is irreducible iff $y$ has no $p$th roots in $K$. So we have to show that $x$ and $y$ have no $p$th roots in $K$, right??
$$$$
We suppose that $x$ has a $p$th rootin $K$, then $\exists b \in K$ such that $b^p=x$.
$t^p-x=t^p-b^p=(t-b)^p$ 
But how can we get a contradiction??

Comment: I got stck right now... Could you explain me further what I am supposed to do??

Comment: 2. $K \leq K(\sqrt[p]{x})\leq E=K(\sqrt[p]{x}, \sqrt[p]{y})$

Then $[E:K]=[E:K(\sqrt[p]{x})] [K(\sqrt[p]{x}):K]$

$[K(\sqrt[p]{x}):K]=degIrr(\sqrt[p]{x}, K)=deg(t^p-x)=p$

$[E:K(\sqrt[p]{x})]=degIrr(\sqrt[p]{y}, K(\sqrt[p]{x}))=deg(t^p-y)=p$

Therefore, $[E:K]=p^2$.

Is it correct??

Comment: What could I improve??

Comment: 4. $a \in E$ that means that $f(a)=0 \Rightarrow g(a)=0 \text{ OR } h(a)=0 \Rightarrow a^p-x=0 \text{ OR } a^p-y=0$  $\Rightarrow a^p=x\in K \text{ OR } a^p=y\in K$ 
Therefore, $a^p \in K$.

Is this correct??

Comment: So, do we take cases for an element $x \in $E$, if $x \in K$, if $x \in K(\sqrt[p]{x})$, or if $x \in K(\sqrt[p]{x})$??